# Decoding a packet - broadcast or multicast

Tags: c, ip, ethernet, packet-sniffers

After looking up packet decoding for multicast and broadcast packets, I am having some difficulties in creating the decision logic.  From what I have read and observed using wireshark (and looked at some of its source) here is what I have found:

*Broadcasts:*

- Special case for 0.0.0.0 or rather dst addr 255.255.255.255
- Local broadcast where IG and LG bits for dst addr are set to 1
- I cannot know what subnet a packet is from and so I cannot determine specific broadcast addresses due to custom sub-netting.
- Should I test and see if dest addr might be a legit broadcast address (i.e. guess cidr?)

Is this sufficient?

*Multicasts:*

- IG bit set to 1, and LG bit set to 0
- dst address destined to 224 - 239 subnet (first octet)

What I have so far?

```
/*
* Is packet destined for a multicast address?
*/
int is_multicast(CONNECTION temp)
{

char *save;
save = strtok(inet_ntoa(temp.ip_dst), ".");

int firstOct = 0;
firstOct = atoi(save);

if((temp.ether_dhost[0] == 1 ) && 
   (temp.ether_dhost[1] == 0 ) &&
   ((firstOct >= 224) && 
   (firstOct <= 239))) 
{
    return 1;

}

return 0;
}

/*
* Is packet destined for a broadcast address?
*/
int is_broadcast(CONNECTION temp)
{

    if ((temp.ether_dhost[0] == 0xFF) &&
        (temp.ether_dhost[1] == 0xFF) &&
        (temp.ether_dhost[2] == 0xFF) &&
        (temp.ether_dhost[3] == 0xFF) &&
        (temp.ether_dhost[4] == 0xFF) &&
        (temp.ether_dhost[5] == 0xFF)) {
        return 1;   // DHCP or ARP 
    } else if ((temp.ether_dhost[0] == 0xFF) &&
           (temp.ether_dhost[1] == 0xFF))
        && (temp.ether_dhost[2] != 0xFF) {
        return 1;   // Other local broadcast
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you interested in IPv4-only solutions or also interested in IPv6?

Comment: @sarnold I am looking for only IPv4 solutions at the moment.  I was just playing around with the multicast code - will update in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of IPv4, for checking multicast, the test for first octect should be sufficient.

```
(224 <= first octect <= 239)
```

For broadcast, I did not understand the `else if()` loop in your code. The first `if()` loop should give desired results.

Comment: Answer is above for others- this should solve known multicasts and broadcasts.  It is important to note that you cannot know other broadcast addresses without knowing subnets - you can guess based on standard network address classes, but it is ultimately guesswork.